# React App not Showing in IE 11 - Fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bulma

I have created a react website. It works in Chrome fine but doesn't render at all in IE 11... See here: http://www.phoenixuas.co.uk.gridhosted.co.uk/

I'm a new to React and the subtle changes in the deployment that come with it. For example, I noticed can't inspect the structure to see if it is a CSS Rendering problem. Is there a tool/technique that would help me inspect the code to figure this out? Any tips would be helpful.

Also worth mentioning that I am using Bulma as a CSS framework... with uses flexbox but I have been assured that it should work with IE 11.

**UPDATE**

It appears that the issue might be a forEach loop and the suggestion was to use a polyfill - what is the correct way to implement the polyfill with my code?

**My Code**

```
import React from 'react';

import {
Component
}
from "react";
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.wordcontributions = [];
  this.svgcontributions = [];
  this.removeAllOn = this.removeAllOn.bind(this);
  this.addOnFromList = this.addOnFromList.bind(this);
  this.addOnFromState = this.addOnFromState.bind(this);
  }

  removeAllOn(){
    this.wordcontributions.forEach(function(el) {
      el.classList.remove('on');
    });
    this.svgcontributions.forEach(function(el) {
      el.classList.remove('on');
    });
  };

  addOnFromList = el => {
    var stateCode = el.getAttribute('data-contribution');
    var svgState = document.querySelector('#' + stateCode);
    el.classList.add('on');
    svgState.classList.add('on');
  };

  addOnFromState = el => {
    var stateId = el.getAttribute('id');
    var wordState = document.querySelector("[data-contribution='" + stateId + "']");
    el.classList.add('on');
    wordState.classList.add('on');
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.wordcontributions = document.querySelectorAll('.list-of-contributions li');
    this.svgcontributions = document.querySelectorAll('#contributions > *');

    this.wordcontributions.forEach(el => {
      el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => this.addOnFromList(el));
      el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => this.removeAllOn());

      el.addEventListener('touchstart', () => {
        this.removeAllOn();
        this.addOnFromList(el);
      });
    });

    this.svgcontributions.forEach(el => {
      el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => this.addOnFromState(el));
      el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => this.removeAllOn());

      el.addEventListener('touchstart', () => {
        this.removeAllOn();
        this.addOnFromState(el);
      });
    });

  }
```

**Polyfill**

```
  if ('NodeList' in window && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    console.info('polyfill for IE11');
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = function (callback, thisArg) {
      thisArg = thisArg || window;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        callback.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this);
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: Check browser console...you have errors in your code (specifically...as far as I can tell...you're using `forEach` in an object which doesn't support it)

Comment: According to Can I Use https://caniuse.com/#search=flex flex box is only partially supported in IE11

Comment: Here's a polyfill that I've used to get forEach working in ie11. https://gist.github.com/bob-lee/e7520bfcdac266e5490f40c2759cc955

Comment: Great - what do I do with this code? Where should it go?

Comment: Don't expect someone else to debug your minified code...

Comment: That is a fair point Adriano - I have added my code and the polyfill above asking for clarity.